# Layout Problems with Qt Designer and PyCharm (high-dpi laptop)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am new to Qt Designer and PyCharm and when I want to make a small program for practice, I have encountered a layout problem.

I use Qt Designer to design the layout and use PyUIC as an external tool to convert my login.ui into login.py.

I use **Form** Layout as my layout and put two pairs of labels and lineEdits.

Before running my program, I press the preview button to check my layout first, every thing looks as expected:
[image: Preview in Qt Designer]

But when I run my program in PyCharm, it looks weird and I don't know why:
[image: Run in PyCharm]

I have two .py files:　login.py and mainn.py

login.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(473, 436)
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(Form)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, 
        self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, 
        self.lineEdit)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, 
        self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, 
        self.lineEdit_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Label 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Label 2"))
```

mainn.py:

```
import sys
import login
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = login.Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

By the my I am running on a **High-DPI** laptop, I'm not sure if this is one of the reason. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: According to the template you use Qt Designer you must use the appropriate widget, in your case the first image the top widget is a Widget so you must use QWidget then change QMainWindow to QWidget

Comment: Thanks! That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `mainn.py` via`CMD` You would see an error message:

`QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout" "to QMainWindow" Form ", which already has a layout`

Try it:

```
import sys
import login
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QMainWindow()         # ---
    MainWindow = QWidget()              # +++
    ui = login.Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!